# REST over SSL in apache Camel

Tags: apache-camel

How to create a REST service(Over SSL) using Apache Camel?
Can CXFRS be used to create REST service and expose over https

Please help

Answer (score 0):

You can build a REST and expose over https using the camel-jetty component. This is very simple and easy to configure.

http://camel.apache.org/jetty.html has details and examples to configure https.

cxf component should support too.